# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' - Flask

Tags: python

I am trying to deploy my NLP project (learning style) using flask, but when I try to access the training page the server gives me: **Internal Server Error** and I face this problem on VScode:

> File "C:\Users\chocl\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17384\1855773603.py", line 114, in train
> model=build_model()
> File "C:\Users\chocl\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17384\1855773603.py", line 14, in build_model
> model.add(Embedding(vocabSize, 200, input_length=48, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))
> File "c:\Users\chocl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\dtensor\utils.py", line 96, in _wrap_function
> init_method(layer_instance, *args, **kwargs)
> File "c:\Users\chocl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\embedding.py", line 131, in **init**
> if input_dim <= 0 or output_dim <= 0:
> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

here is the preprocessing page:

```
@app.route("/preprocessing")
def processing():
global df,cv,x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test

df['new_Sentence'] = df['Sentence']
df['new_Sentence'] = df['new_Sentence'].apply(lambda x:lemm.lemmatize(x))
df['new_Sentence'] = df['new_Sentence'].apply(remove_stopwords)
df['new_Sentence'] = df['new_Sentence'].apply(clean)
df['new_Sentence'] = df['new_Sentence'].apply(remove_punctuation_func)


X = df['new_Sentence']
y = df['Type']
# x = cv.fit_transform(df.new_Sentence)
y = le.fit_transform(y)
y = to_categorical(y)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

# Tokenize words
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)
sequences_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
sequences_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)
x_train = pad_sequences(sequences_train, maxlen=48, truncating='pre')
x_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test, maxlen=48, truncating='pre')
vocabSize = len(tokenizer.index_word) + 1

# Read GloVE embeddings
path_to_glove_file = 'glove.6B.200d.txt'
num_tokens = vocabSize
embedding_dim = 200
embeddings_index = {}

# Read word vectors
with open(path_to_glove_file,encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        word, coefs = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        coefs = np.fromstring(coefs, "f", sep=" ")
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs
# Assign word vectors to our dictionary/vocabulary
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_tokens, embedding_dim))
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
       embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
data = {'page':'processing page','message':'ok'}
return jsonify(data)
```

and the training page:

```
@app.route("/train")
def train():
global model,x_train,y_train
model=build_model()
model.fit(x_train,
                y_train,
                validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                verbose=1,
                batch_size=64,
                epochs=10)  
data = {'page':'train page','message':'ok'}
return jsonify(data)
```

And the model used in the training page:

```
def build_model(): 
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabSize, 200, input_length=len(x_train[1]), weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])    
return model
```

Any clue, How to tackle this problem !!

Comment: Hi, please show all the error code so that we can trace the issue easier

Comment: Please edit your question, and edit the error to every error that you seen on your screen.

Comment: @Joshua - check the edited question, is it okay now !!

Comment: I checked your error code, it said the error occurred at your model.add(Embedding…. , please try to convert the vocabSize variable to int.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your error code, you can see your error highlighted that it occur at your first model.add.

After reading the documentation, they mentioned the first parameter to be input_dim, which is your vocabSize, so I assume that your vocabSize variable is string type instead of int type

Edit* add on document page
https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/

Please change the code to the below

```
model.add(Embedding(int(vocabSize), 200, input_length=len(x_train[1]), weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))
```

Comment: Now it gave me a new error: **model.add(Embedding(int(vocabSize), 200, input_length=48, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

Comment: Do you mind sharing what did you put as vocabSize?

Comment: do "print(vocabSize)" just before this like, you have wrong value there

Comment: vocabSize = len(tokenizer.index_word) + 1, It's mentioned in the preprocessing page code, `VocabSize = len(tokenizer.index_word) + 1`
`print(f"Vocabulary Size = {vocabSize}")`, Vocabulary Size = 26645

Comment: Can you print vocabSize above the model.add and tell me the output, I suspect vocabSize is empty

Comment: this is from the preprocessing page"before model.add": `{"Vocabs":26843,"message":"ok","page":"processing page"}`, So it's not empty, and also I think there is no need for the `model.add(Embedding(int(vocabSize)` because it's already an integer

Comment: Hi, preprocessing page does not mean train page, could you please add the print(vocabSize) just a line above of the model.add and update us what did you see?

Comment: Okay, if you know that your vocabSize is 26843, let’s try by replacing vocabSize with 26843, see if it works. model.add(Embedding(int(26843), 200, input_length=48, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))

Comment: I tried to set vocabSize to 26843 manually, but it didn't work, it said that it's not compatible with embedding_matrix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249519/discussion-between-ahmed-adel-and-joshua).